# LeaftLet map is not loading in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, map

I have a simple leaflet map in LWC, libraries are loading successfully, however, the map is not rendering.

Am I missing anything wrong?

```
<template>
  <div class="map-root" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import Leaflet from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/Leaflet";
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
export default class MapComponent extends LightningElement {
  map;
  markerGroup;

  renderedCallback() {
    this.initializeLeaflet();
  }

  initializeLeaflet() {
    Promise.all([
      loadStyle(this, Leaflet + "/leaflet.css"),
      loadScript(this, Leaflet + "/leaflet.js")
    ])
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Leaflet Initialized");
        const mapRoot = this.template.querySelector(".map-root");
        mapRoot.style = "height: " + this.height + ";";
        this.map = L.map(mapRoot, { zoomControl: false }).setView(
          [32.95574, -96.824257],
          14
        ); // Default View
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error loading leaflet styles", error.message);
      });
  }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: `mapRoot.style = "height: " + this.height + ";"; ` Where your height is comming from?

Comment: you should have a look here too, look like missing a token connection  : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation

Comment: I completely missed the height variable....:( shame on me. it works fine. thank you